# Visual Studio Code - Copilot brushes appear to do nothing?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I'm trying out copilot and I feel like I am missing something.

Most of it seems to do very little or just doesn't work. For example:

1. Highlight code
2. Click the DOCUMENT brush

I expect it to add comments. I've tried clicking other brushes and they all seem to do nothing. The code explainer works but it seems more cumbersome then just asking ChatGPT outright.

Am I doing something wrong with the brushes?

### Update

- I realized the plugin had crashed. I rebooted vscode and that got it running
- I hit the document brush it added nothing. It just copied and pasted the code block I had highlighted
- Make readable just deleted comments that I needed
- Make robust deleted all my code and replaced it with a few nonsense lines.

Am I missing some serious part of the configuration?